# JSP - Image Button becomes an image after clicking on it

Tags: jsp

I'm creating a jsp page that requires an image button to send a value to my servlet and subsequently become a static image after being clicked on.

Is there an easy way to do this without using additional libraries?  How do I receive and manipulate the response object in the jsp page after my servlet has confirmed it has received the value from the jsp page?  Is there a way to differentiate the different buttons clicked as well?

Thank you!

With much thanks,
A young and newbie programmer.

Answer (score 0):

You may use JSTL `<c:choose/>` to compare a attribute value which is returned from the servlet's response.

Jsp page - page1.jsp

```
<c:choose>
    <c:when test="${status=='ok'}">
        <form method="post" action="your_servlet">
            ..other stuff
            <input type="image" src="images/image1.jpg"/>
        </form>
    </c:when>
    <c:otherwise>
        <img src="images/image1.jpg"/>
    </c:otherwise>
</c:choose>
```

In servlet you have to set status attribute and use getRequestDispatcher() to forward the request.

```
request.setAttribute("status","ok");
request.getRequestDispatcher("/page1.jsp").forward(request,response);
```